# Intel Integrated Graphics misidentification (DXGI)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, graphics, directx, dxgi

I'm filling a window with a blank swap chain that's being handled by DirectX 12. While fooling a round a bit with Explicit Multi-Adapter, I came across this weird behaviour...

As shown in pretty much all DX12 demo code in existence so far, I loop through all DXGI adapters that I get using `IDXGIFactory4::EnumAdapters1()` to find the most suitable (or in my case every) adapter at `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0` or higher. And as shown in the demos, I discard all adapters that have the `DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_SOFTWARE` like this:

```
if ((adapterDesc.Flags & DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_SOFTWARE) != FALSE) 
    continue; // Check the next adapter.
```

In my implementation I then dump all compatible adapters into a `std::vector` to be used later.

If I use a breakpoint to check how everything looks at runtime, I notice my adapter list only contains one adapter after the loop has exited, which is not what I would expect, as I have both an NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M and an Intel HD Graphics 4000.

By breaking during the loop and checking the `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC2` structure for each adapter, I find that the one I get is indeed the GT 650M, so that means my integrated graphics is identifying itself as a software adapter.

This is plausible on its own, but if you look at a [picture of an Ivy Bridge die](http://images.anandtech.com/reviews/cpu/intel/IvyBridge/review/Ivy-Bridge_Die_Label.jpg) (which is what I have) you see a big area cordoned off as *"Processor Graphics"*, which Intel themselves define like this: *"Processor graphics refer to graphics that are physically in the processor package or integrated into the processor silicon."* That just screams "hardware adapter" at me.

If I remove the above code block I do indeed get two adapters in my list, but the second one identifies itself as *"Microsoft Basic Render Driver"* and gives a vendor ID of `0x1414`, while Google says that Intel usually returns `0x8086` as its ID. [This list](http://pcidatabase.com/vendors.php?sort=id) doesn't even mention the owner of `0x1414`.

And, to make things even more confusing, if I check the Information Center in my Intel HD Graphics Control Panel it says it has a vendor ID of `0x8086`!

Before anyone asks: Yes, my drivers should be up-to-date; I updated them as soon as I noticed this. Strangely though, DxDiag gives me an incorrect driver date for the integrated graphics, but does the same (though slightly closer to the truth) for the GT 650M. The discrete GPU driver is of WDDM 2.0, while the integrated graphics driver is of WDDM 1.3, which might be relevant, because I think it should be of 2.0 too. (Might the update have failed?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary reason for the `if (adapterDesc.Flags & DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_SOFTWARE)` filter is to avoid selecting the *Microsoft Basic Render Driver*. This uses the WARP11 software device which does not support DirectX 12.

> WARP11 is supported in all versions of Windows with DirectX 11. WARP12 is currently a developer only device (i.e. "Graphics Tools" optional feature-on-demand is installed).

It's probably a bug if your discrete part is returning true for this flag. It might be a bug in your code, a driver bug, or some strange side-effect of Optimus-style selection. WARP / MBR is really the only thing that is expected to return `DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_SOFTWARE`.

You can also exclude MBR via a `if ( ( adapterDesc.VendorId == 0x1414 ) && ( adapterDesc.DeviceId == 0x8c ) )` test for [well-known VendorID/DeviceID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205075.aspx#WARP_new_for_Win8), but I suggest digging your code to understand why you are incorrectly getting `DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_SOFTWARE` returned for hardware devices.

See [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I pretty much copied the demo code, so I'd be surprised if it already goes wrong there.

Comment: You might want to look at the DirectX 12 version of [DeviceResources](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DeviceResources).